# Android activity navigation save state

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, state

In the main activity `ActivityA` I replace `FragmentA` by fragment `FragmentB`. From `FragmentB` the user can start a new activity `ActivityB`. By hitting the back button in `ActivityB`, `ActivityA` is displayed showing `FragmentA`. I was expecting to see `FragmentB` with its last state. Do I have to save the state of the previous activities separately to provide this behaviour?

```
ActivityA(FragmentA) -> ActivityA(FragmentB) -> ActivityB 
BACK
ActivityA(FragmentB)
```

In the main activity I set the current fragment using:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.a_main_frame_content, new FragmentB())
               .addToBackStack(null)
               .commit();
```

From the fragment I start a new activity using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

`ActivityA` is set as parent activity for `ActivityB` to provide proper navigation.

**[UPDTATE]** It looks like the problem lies in the different behaviour of navigating back and navigating up. If I navigate back, the activity is displayed in its last state while navigating up forces the activity to recreate.

Comment: can you post activity A full code?

Comment: does my solution works for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets try this:

In the intent of the parentActivity(if you can set it before you create parentActivity its best, otherwise you may have to use setIntent):

```
    currentActivityIntent.putExtra("random-unique-key-for-each-activity",
random-unique-key-for-each-activity);
```

And before you create a child activity, u put following in a map:

```
myKeyIntentMap.put(random-unique-key-for-each-activity, currentActivityIntent);
```

In the method triggered on "Up" event :

```
{
String parentKey = currentActivity.parentActivity.getIntent.getStringExtra("random-unique-key-for-each-activity");
Intent intentToLaunch = (Intent)myKeyIntentMap.get(parentKey);
intentToLaunch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );
startActivity(intentToLaunch);
}
```

This way, using the intent, even if your History Stack is A-someAct1-someAct2-B, and u launch intent resolving to A, it will be "brought to front" killing someActs.

P.S. I havent done any null checks and havent kept in mind the exact method names, just given you an approach.

Comment: This could actually work. But I guess I misinterpreted the design guidelines. By doing something like this the ``UP`` button would behave not as desired to be behave.

Comment: IMO u dint ask for something unacceptable, going up to a previous screen doesnt mean that it has to reload the screen. The intent flags are meant for bringing an existing act to the front or launch new etc., so it all depends on how it fits your app. If going UP needs that previous state of your parent activity must be preserved, you can use my solution otherwise go with what they offer. But ideally i wud have liked an option to specify, if i want to go to previous state or fresh state.

Answer (score 3):

Behaviour of "up" is sometimes misleading indeed. When I faced similar problem I preferred to save my time and not deal with saving states.
You can quickly solve it by catching your navigation "up" event in your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to determine whether there is an activity in the backstack? What do I do if my application directly starts in this activity?

Comment: well, I think you don't have to. with this code everything will work as expected: when you'll press back or up being in last backstack state (activity's or fragment's), you'll leave app. Framework will do all work for you. try it.

Comment: Is there any way to say: `If up-activity == back-activty then onBackPressed()`?

Comment: why do you need that? as far as I know up-activity is always equals to back-activty.

Comment: No, that's not true. Up points always to the logical parent of an activity, while back points to the last activity viewed. Up vs. Back: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: ok, but from your link: "When the previously viewed screen is also the hierarchical parent of the current screen, pressing the Back button has the same result as pressing an Up button" Isn't it your case? Have you tested it? "while back points to the last activity viewed" - I think that's not true, it leads to the previous "screen", according to docs, which in your case is previous Fragment or Activity

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because when you are moving to `ActivityB` activityA is going to puse and destroy state respectively, thus when you back to activity `ActivityA` ActivityA is starting again thus you are getting fragmentA as view. you need to save the state using sharedPfer. Use some flag to save the state in your `onCreateView()` check the state and set correct fragment for the view. Hope you have got my point.

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "mypref";
boolean isVisited;
//check sharedpref
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
 isVisited= settings.getBoolean("isVisited", false);

if(!isVisited){
// set fragmentA
}else{ 
// set fragmentB
}


// inside fragment transaction block

Editor edit = settings.editor();
isVisited.setBoolean(true);
edit.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, got it. But does this also mean that I have to save the state of the views of the fragment as well? Like the data and scroll position of a ListView?

Comment: if you want to display specific then you can save those state as well.

Comment: @Yup when we move activity A to B ,it call OnPause and OnStop of activity A not OnDestroy.